# How does this partial-string color-highlighting code work?

Tags: color, text-decorations

I'm using the `awesome-cv` class, which highlights the first three letters of the section heading like so:

[image: Education with "Edu" highlighted]

The code that produces this effect looks like this:

```
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{awesome-red}{HTML}{DC3522}
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\else%
        awesome\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}
```

The text size and boldface are added later in

```
\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{15pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{text}\@sectioncolor #1}}
```

**How does the first part of this code highlight the first three letters?**

---

I understand that this isn't a MWE, but I wasn't able to create one out of the `.cls` file and I don't think this code is that complex to someone who knows what they're looking at. If I need and MWE, let me know.

Comment: The parameters to `\@sectioncolor` are the first three characters `#1#2#3`. Similar to how `\frac12` produces the fraction `1/2`. Note that when `\@sectioncolor` is called its parameters are _not_ enclosed in a brace group.

Comment: I thought that was the case. But what happens to the rest of it, and why is there a case statement? Taking out `#3` doesn't change the highlighting to the first two characters, it causes a crash.

Comment: Did you also change the second `#1#2#3` to `#1#2` following the `color`? If you changed it  `#1#2#3` to `#1#2` in _both_ places it should highlight just the first two characters.  After the first three characters are processed, `\@sectioncolor` has done its on and the remaining characters are just text that is _not_ processed by ``\@sectioncolor`. Same as `$\frac`123$` producing the fraction `1/2` followed by `3`.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't compiling because I had the .pdf open in another window, not because of my edits to the code. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, this trick is quite simple: Arguments to normal TeX commands can either be single tokens (i.e. characters or `\controlsequence`s), or they can be token sequences enclosed in braces. For example this is why, in math mode, you can write `\frac 1 2`, `\frac{1}{2}` or even `\frac1{2}` and get the same result.

Therefore, all you need to do to get the first three characters of a word is a command with three arguments. For example,

```
\newcommand\mycommand[3]{%
    \textcolor{red}{#1}%
    \textcolor{green}{#2}%
    \textcolor{blue}{#3}%
}
```

allows you to highlight the first three letters following an invocation like `\mycommand hello`. The `lo` in this case is simply not part of the command.

To get the familiar syntax with just one parameter in braces, you can wrap this command in another command:

```
\newcommand*\myothercommand[1]{%
    \mycommand #1%
}
```

This allows you to write `\myothercommand{hello}`.

Here's a MWE that demonstrates a stripped-down version of the command with different colors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}

\definecolor{awesome-red}{HTML}{DC3522}
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\newcommand\sectioncolor[3]{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        awesome\or%
        green\or%
        blue\or%
        orange\or%
        yellow\else%
        cyan\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{15pt}{1em}\bfseries\sectioncolor #1}}

\begin{document}
    \sectionstyle{first}\par
    \sectionstyle{second}\par
    \sectionstyle{third}\par
    \sectionstyle{fourth}\par
    \sectionstyle{fifth}\par
    \sectionstyle{sixth}\par
    \sectionstyle{seventh}
\end{document}
```

[image: colorful output]

Comment: Ah, I understand now. That is a neat trick. But why is there a counter in the example?

Comment: It appears to be rather useless in this case. But if you insert different colors in the cases (instead of `awesome` for all of them), you can have it use different colors on the first few invocations.