# Change twenty-second CV to colour first word

Tags: pdftex

I am making a resume using the [twenty second CV template](https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex). This colours in the first 3 letters of a section heading in the main column. I would like to extend this to colour the first word of the section heading.

As far as I can tell, the relevant bits of the .cls file start at line 238:

```
\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{
  {%
  % Switch between blue and gray
   \round{#1#2#3}{%
      \ifodd\value{colorCounter}%
        mainblue%
      \else%
        maingray%
      \fi%
    }%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par%
  {%
    \LARGE 
    \color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}
```

I understand that `@sectioncolor#1#2#3` takes the first three letters/tokens of the section title and colours them, and that I can extend this (at least as long as the section title) by appending #4... etc. I can also change the colour of the whole title, but haven't yet worked out how to change only the first word.

I have read a few other questions on similar topics, but they use a different CV template and I haven't been able to convert those solutions to this particular problem:

- [Change the color of section titles to include whole word in Awesome CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509756/change-the-color-of-titles-to-include-whole-word-in-awesome-cv)
- [Changing AwesomeCV section highlighting to highlight whole first word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563898/changing-awesomecv-section-highlighting-to-highlight-whole-first-word)
- [All section titles in one uniform color in friggeri Latex CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304216/all-section-titles-in-one-uniform-color-in-friggeri-latex-cv)
- [Explanation for a latex def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694598/explanation-for-a-latex-def)
- [How does this partial-string color highlighting work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300584/how-does-this-partial-string-color-highlighting-code-work)
- [Variable color for section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145076/variable-color-for-section-titles)

EDIT:

After Simon's answer below, I made some edits to the `.cls` file that rotate the colours through a list.

```
RequirePackage{parskip}
\RequirePackage{xstring}

%%% Counter and colour first word
\newcounter{colorCounter}
\makeatletter
\def\@sectioncolor#1{%
    \StrBetween[1,2]{ #1 }{ }{ }[\FirstWord]
    \StrBehind{#1}{\FirstWord}[\LastWords]
    {\color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        pblue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        blue\or%
        green\or%
        purple\else%
        pblue\fi%
    }
    \FirstWord}\LastWords
    \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%    
    \par%
    {%
        \LARGE 
        \color{headercolor}%
        \@sectioncolor{#1}%
    }
    \par\vspace{\parskip}
}   
\makeatother
%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code between `\documentclass[]{twentysecondcv}` and `\begin{document}`

```
% **************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter

\def\@sectioncolor#1{%
    \StrBetween[1,2]{ #1 }{ }{ }[\FirstWord]
    \StrBehind{#1}{\FirstWord}[\LastWords]  
    {\round{\FirstWord}{%
        \ifodd\value{colorCounter}%
        mainblue%
        \else%
        maingray%
        \fi%
        }\LastWords%
    }%
    \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%    
    \par%
    {%
        \LARGE 
        \color{headercolor}%
        \@sectioncolor{#1}%
    }
    \par\vspace{\parskip}
}   
\makeatother
% *****************************************************
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thanks, this worked brilliantly. I ended up making some changes to the `.cls` file and also letting it cycle between a set of colours, but couldn't have got there without you and your use of xstring.

Comment: hello! how this should change if i want that all words are highlighted? In the example, only the word "other" is in blue, how should i change it for "other information"? thanks.